# Tests annotated with org.junit.Test are not recognized

Tags: spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

Whenever I annotate a test with  `org.junit.Test`  the test is not recognized during  `mvn test`  or  `mvn clean install`  .But it's recognized when I annotate it with `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;` 
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.****.it.daas.apibuilder</groupId>
    <artifactId>requestservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Request Service</name>
    <description>Request service for RabbitMQ Message Handler</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.*****.it.daas.apibuilder.submitrequestservice.SubmitRequestApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
<!-- UNIT Testing libraries -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
            <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

<!-- RabbitMQ dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
            <artifactId>amqp-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<!-- MAILING DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    <!-- POSTGRES CONNECTION DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    <!-- HIKARI CP CONNECTION POOLING  -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- JSON OBJECT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20180813</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- Google HTTP CLIENT -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.23.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <!-- Cloud config dependencies -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>Greenwich.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.spring.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>

    <!-- Actuators -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <!-- Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    <!-- WEB -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>



</project>
```

Is there someway I can ask maven to pick up tests annotated with org.junit.Test ?

Update:- Added full pom.xml for reference 
I'm using powermockito as well to stub my static methods. 
Please let me know if I can add anything else as well so that it would help you debug the issues

Comment: what is the name of your class which contains Test method?

Comment: PostgresConnectionServiceImplTest

Comment: Can you pls post your complete pom.xml file?

Comment: did you configure this `maven-surefire-plugin` in your pom.xml ?

Comment: @RitikaGoel added pom.xml .

Comment: @CodeScale Please go through the updated pom.xml I've added the full pom for your reference

Comment: Check your class path... you should have junit 5 in it...so the algorithm of surefire run the junit 5 platform. `mvn dependency::tree`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see in pom.xml, there are a couple of redundant dependencies present. The reason `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test` gets picked is because it is a part of Junit5 and that is added as a maven-dependency with `spring-boot-starter-test`. Basically, your problem is you are using 2 different version of junit - 4 & 5.

In case, you want to use junit 4, please remove dependency - `spring-boot-starter-test` and give it a try.

Please let me know the results. Hope this will help in debugging further!

Comment: There is no problem to use starter-test with junit 4.

Comment: @CodeScale By default starter-test uses junit 5, and the pom.xml has both spring-boot-starter-test as well as junit 4...These are conflicting. Since the requirement is that tests written with org.junit.Test should get picked we would need only junit4 to be present on classpath. :)

Comment: @DwijrajBhattacharyya Perfect!!

Comment: @RitikaGoel Disagree.... I repeat "you can use both together". See my answer but remove the starter is not the best solution here.

Comment: The point is to have both, `junit-vintage-engine` and `junit-jupite-engine` on the test-classpath.

Answer (score 1):

Actually your problem is here

```xml
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

by excluding `junit-vintage-engine` **you said that you don't have any junit4 testcases in your application**. But it is not the case....

So no need to remove the entire dependency.... just remove the exclusion and your junit4 testcases will run.

Comment: The point is to have both, `junit-vintage-engine` and `junit-jupite-engine` on the test-classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, you are running it from IDE, if that's the case, please check that you have not selected Junit5 under "Run Configurations". That option you can find within this dialog,

[image]

Hope this helps, please let me know otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run the JUnit4 and JUnit5 test simultaneously, you have to currently do it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-4-5</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The console output:

```
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) @ junit-4-5 ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running pkg.JUnit5Test
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.053 s - in pkg.JUnit5Test
[INFO] Running pkg.JUnit4Test
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.035 s - in pkg.JUnit4Test
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

and the tests:

```
import org.junit.Test;

public class JUnit4Test {
    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
}


import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class JUnit5Test {
    @Test
    public void test() {

    }
}
```

In the future version 3.0.0-M5 of Surefire and Failsafe it will be easier for you and no engine will be needed:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.13</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```